# outlook vba script error

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm running the following code in every received email:

```
Dim globalWrongExt As Boolean
Dim globalcontainsZip As Boolean
Dim globalTotalSize As Double


Sub sortingP8(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
'Check each attachment

globalTotalSize = 0
globalcontainsZip = False
globalWrongExt = False

Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set nonIngFolder = ns.Folders("Pasdasd@xasxax.com").Folders("Non-ingestible Items")
Set ingFolder = ns.Folders("Pasdasd@xasxax.com").Folders("Ingestible Items")
Set zipFolder = ns.Folders("Pasdasd@xasxax.comk").Folders("ZIP files")

'Check extensions
extensionCheck Item

'Move email to the appropiate folder
If (globalWrongExt = True Or globalTotalSize > 10000000) Then
    Item.Move nonIngFolder
ElseIf (globalcontainsZip = True) Then
    Item.Move zipFolder
Else
    Item.Move ingFolder
End If

End Sub

Private Sub extensionCheck(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim olkAtt As Outlook.Attachment
'Check each attachment

For Each olkAtt In Item.Attachments
    Dim extension As String
    extension = Right(LCase(olkAtt.FileName), 4)
    'If the attachment's file name ends with .zip
    globalTotalSize = globalTotalSize + olkAtt.Size

    If extension = ".msg" Then
        extensionCheck olkAtt
    ElseIf extension <> ".ppt" And extension <> ".doc" And extension <> ".pdf" And extension <> ".jpg" And extension <> ".zip" And extension <> ".docx" And extension <> ".pptx" And extension <> ".htm" And extension <> ".html" And extension <> ".gif" And extension <> ".tif" Then
        globalWrongExt = True
    ElseIf extension = ".zip" Then
        globalcontainsZip = True
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

When debugging, the following line fails:

```
If extension = ".msg" Then
    **extensionCheck olkAtt**
```

Is it possible to cast the olkAtt object as a Outlook.MailItem.

Or maybe a workaround for the script. What I want to achieve is a recursive function to be called in every .msg attachment to evaluate the attachments included.

Comment: what is the output of the exception?

Comment: Just Run-time error '13':
Type mismatch

Answer (score 0):

You dimmed

```
Dim olkAtt As Outlook.Attachment
```

and then called

```
extensionCheck olkAtt
```

which receives a MailItem:

```
Private Sub extensionCheck(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
```

if you are positive olkAtt is a MailItem, then you should have another object of type MailItem, set it to olkAtt, and then pass it to extensionCheck:

```
Dim ToBeTested as MailItem
Set ToBeTested = olkAtt
extensionCheck(ToBeTested)
```

This way you won't get the Type Mismatch error.